# how to pop a dialog box on button click

Tags: javascript

Hello Friends
I want to upload a image but according to requirement when click on button a pop window display and inner part of pop window display browse field using code something like

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="">
    <div><label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="form[name]" /></div>
    <div><label>File:</label> <input type="file" name="form[file]" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></div>
</form>
```

actually i want to show this browse field in pop-up window.
Please reply me regard this 
Thanks

Comment: Learn to format your code... its so unreadable and spelling so many errors.

Comment: So the user will have to click "Twice" just to see the "select file" window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a `myform` ID to your form hide it, using `display:none;` and try this code

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('myform').style.display='';">Show Browse</a>
```

### UPDATE

I have created a demo of what you wanted. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rVw9M/

Since you are unfamilier with jquery, you need jquery library for this to run put this in your head (HTML Pages' Head :D)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: ya i know sir  my code is unreadable.but I don't know how to post as u post above.ur code is readable and look good and also show scrolling. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Shalu, ha ha, I will fix your question for now, but just go and use the tools to get use to it.

Comment: No Sir i don't want to show or hide a div.My requirement is something like a light box but not exactly the light box.

Comment: Something? Please Explain in detail

Comment: I don't know how to use tools any reference?

Comment: Even lightbox, is simple mechanism of show and hide....... Are you familier with jQuery... I could provide you with a better solution.

Comment: just see this url there is button choosefile click that it open a window over a cards i want something like but inner part of window i want to show browse field.I don't  want to show or hide a div because when div show it take space at that time my cards goes down.when hide div cards again take previous position.

Comment: I saw your link, but it is not popping on button click as you are saying in your question...

Comment: No I m not familier with jQuery .But Try

Comment: I know but not find out the word for this.

Comment: see this link its exact according to my requirment.  `http://www.101shortsale.com/contact/# `

Comment: Are u there ?Thanks Sir u r replying me

Comment: @shalu, if you want, we might also chat

Comment: @shalu, even the page you gave is also showing and hiding division. I will post a jquery code showing a sample of how to create that effect in some time.

Comment: Shalu, C the update of my answer, that should be what you want, if it is not then you might chat here or facebook.

Comment: its exactly according to my requirements.but i want show u a file where i use.This code not working in my file i think  its only because i don't have knowledge of jQuery.

Comment: I have also given you steps to use it. You need to have jquery library to use this. Copy the link I have provided on my post, then copy all the codes from the demo and it will work.

Comment: ya I saw ur demo and paste in my php file but not working i dont know why

Comment: put this in the head section `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>`

Comment: There is not any option from where i can attach a file?

Comment: Come to Jquery Chat room of this website, from the top part.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, here is how you could achieve that (just off the top of my head):

a) Create a new separate page and move your code into this page

b) On the existing page create a DIV and add IFRAME into it which would be pointed to that new page, e.g.

```
<div class="uploader" style="display: none;">
  <iframe scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="url"></iframe>
</div>
```

c) Download and add some modal popup plugin - personally, I prefer [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

d) Now you can show your popup by calling modal() method on the .uploader class, something like this..

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('.uploader').modal();">Show Uploader</a>
```

Comment: wouldn't use an iframe unless there's a ton of HTML... in this case there isn't. just inline it. actually, if there was, then you'd use ajax.

Comment: yup.. I'm totally agree on Ajax, just was not sure if the author could handle more advanced concepts.